# Can I install mainline kernel in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, mainline-kernel

Can I download latest .deb file of kernel from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ (for example v3.7-rc1-quantal) and install it on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (precise) or any old Ubuntu like 10.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You should note that rc can be unstable. If you are adventurous and want to customize the kernel, downloading release package(s) directly from http://kernel.org/, building, and installing can be an option. Have fun.

Update: If you have installed virtualbox, vmware, and/or nvidia, you may want to hold off on using kernel v3.7-rc*. These require patches for building kernel modules. Issues are related to VM_RESERVED macro and include/linux/version.h header file. Am sure these issues will get resolved in coming days.